# No Pull Request to forked Repo

Tags: git, github

I've forked a repo from a friend. When forking it(a little time ago) it was private. Now the repo becomes public(don't ask why) and if I push commits to my repo and want to make a pull request, I cannot. There are no message that I forked this repo. Do anybody has a solution for this problem?

Comment: You might want to get in touch with GitHub support - they sometimes can fix things like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fork the public repository again so the PRs will work. You can also remove the old fork so you do not have to pick a different name.